# JAVASCRIPT 2D Platformer objects do not appear on screen

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision-detection

I have been coding with javascript for about 3 months now and I decided to start working on a 2D Platform game for my Advanced Higher project. I found a very helpful tutorial online which showed each step of the creation process and even supplied the source code. The problem is that whenever I run the source code, the game does not load properly. At this stage I am faced with a totally blank screen but a sized canvas. I deconstructed the tutorial and followed it step by step but still nothing. Anyone have an ideas?

I apologise if it is not a lot to go by, however I do know that the problem most likely lies in the update function

I coded this using Sublime Text 2 For Mac

```js
function update()   {
  // controls
    if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
        // up arrow or space
      if(!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
       player.jumping = true;
       player.grounded = false;
       player.velY = -player.speed*2;
      }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {             
            player.velX++;         
         }     
    }     
    if (keys[37]) {         
        // left arrow         
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }
 
    player.velX *= friction;
    player.velY += gravity;
 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();

player.grounded = false;
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);

    var dir = colCheck(player, boxes[i]);


    if (dir === "l" || dir === "r") {
        player.velX = 0;
        player.jumping = false;
    } else if (dir === "b") {
        player.grounded = true;
        player.jumping = false;
    } else if (dir === "t") {
        player.velY *= 0;
    }

}

 if(player.grounded) {
    player.velY = 0;


player.x += player.velX;
player.y += player.VelY;

ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
 
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

  function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
    // get the vectors to check against
    var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
        vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
        // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
        hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
        hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
        colDir = null;
 
    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
    if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {         // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)         var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),             oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);         if (oX >= oY) {
            if (vY > 0) {
                colDir = "t";
                shapeA.y += oY;
            } else {
                colDir = "b";
                shapeA.y -= oY;
            }
        } else {
            if (vX > 0) {
                colDir = "l";
                shapeA.x += oX;
            } else {
                colDir = "r";
                shapeA.x -= oX;
            }
        }
    }
    return colDir;

  }
 
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
 
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
 
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});
```

Comment: Any error in your js console when you use console.log()?

Comment: Do you know about the developer consoles browsers have? for example, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I just had a look at the Console and it returned this 
 Uncaught ReferenceError: oX is not defined

Comment: You have 3 lines that seem to have been commented out accidentally -- `var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX), oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY); if (oX >= oY) {` -- insert a line break to restore them

Comment: Yup, that fixed most of the problem! thank you :) now the only thing that is going wrong is that The avatar is not showing up. All the platforms and boarders are present however the red rectangle that represents the player is now missing
http://gyazo.com/033e35e6850a8262f5c17e4115719f54

Comment: You don't really need to use beginPath, fill, and rect... simply clear the screen and use fillRect (I tried and rect doesn't work)